# How to express the idea that a wound has young skin when it is healing?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I have a scrape on my knee.

At first, the scrape is covered in dried blood and I don't want to break it off because it might bleed.

After a week, the dried blood breaks off by itself and I can see young skin.

Do we say "**the wound has young skin and about to heal**" in every English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“My wound has granulating tissue.”
Granulating tissue is the active formation of new skin. It is more of a medical term, rather than everyday language.
Alternatively, you could say, “I have a newly healed wound and the tissue is still pink.”

Answer (score 3):

The dried blood is called a [scab](https://kidshealth.org/en/kids/scab.html). As you see from the last paragraph, what is underneath when it falls off is usually called *new* skin rather than *young.*

Answer (score 2):

"New skin" would be better than "young skin".  So something like "The scrape on my knee is healing up. The scab has come off and new skin has formed over the wound"

It's rather unclear why you would be describing this.  Are you talking to your doctor over the phone or something like that?  I can't imagine trying to give this kind of detail in normal conversation.  If someone asked me about my knee, I'd probably just say "It's getting better."